# Mutual recursion in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion

I'd like to know how is it possible to get mutual recursion with Regex in Javascript.

For instance, a regex recognising the language {a^n b^n} would be /a$0b/ where $0 stands for the current regex. It would be basic recursion.

Mutual recursion is the same, but with different regexs.

How can we get it done with Javascript ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: JS doesn't even support "basic" recursion in regular expression.

Comment: Mutual recursion should be pretty trivial by inlining the one expression in the other.

Comment: Not so easy. Because A invokes B and B invokes A. So it doesn't work.

(That's why it is "recursion")

Comment: Yes, and when you inline B in A then A invokes A and you've got your basic recursion. Which of course still isn't supported in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Javascript doesn't have support for recursive regular expressions.

You can implement a basic recursive function with checks for the first and last letter (to ensure they're `a` and `b` respectively) and a recursive call for the interior string (the `$0` in your example).

For one, you realize that this language produces phrases that have strictly an even number of letters, so you can implement a check to break out early.

Secondly, your only other failure case is if the letters at each end don't match.

You can map any other regular expression to such a tester function. To implement a mutually recursive one, simply call one function from the other.

To truly embody a finite-state machine, go token by token when you do the checks; for the example above, first check that you have an `a` at the beginning, then recurse, then check for the `b` at the end.

The `a^n b^n` language you are describing isn't even a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar#Mixing_left_and_right_regular_rules), and so a mutually recursive language would be far from it. You cannot use the regular expression engine in Javascript to produce a mutually recursive language, which is why you need to write a finite-state machine to take a token at a time and proceed to the next state if we encounter a match.

Comment: I don't want to make a function for each regex.
That's why there is a regex engine I guess :D

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. You can't do this with Javascript regexes. Regular expressions are parsed with finite-state machines under the hood anyway, there's nothing inefficient or impractical with doing it this way.

Comment: There is theory behind this. Regular languages are those that can be represented using regular expressions. Javascript regexes follow that strictly. Recursive regexes aren't actually regular expressions in the strict sense; they are what we call context-free grammars. Context-free languages are represented by context-free grammars, which are just finite-state machines that take tokens and advance the state of the phrase we are constructing. This is the behavior you want to simulate using functions. There is no other way.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar#Mixing_left_and_right_regular_rules) is a good resource that deals with the `a^n b^n` example.

Comment: I didn't expect "Regex" to be real Regular Expressions, nor to not use a finite automata internally.*

Comment: What were you expecting, then? What kind of answer here will be effective for you? :)

Comment: I thought it began with only regex, and then, kept the name ^^. I was expecting someking of marpa, or the use of Earlay parser. I found something usefull though : nearley, it's a nodejs parser which does what I needed to !

Comment: What I described in my answer is essentially a recursive descent parser. You check for the terminals normally, and call the routines for the nonterminals. if any of these fail/return false, the main routine returns false. It's really simple since you already have the grammar you need to conform to, but will take a bit of code.

Comment: I wanted to get a parser maker. From a grammar you get a parser. (Because lately, I've been making basic parsers, and there is just way too much boilerplate code)